# How to use a tp4056 and a lithium battery on an esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino, batteries

I am new to IOT and I would like to have your opinion on my wiring, I want to power my project with a lithium battery for that I use a tp4056 to charge my battery but also to power my breadboard I would like to know if my wiring is good for the battery or if I need to make some changes

I use 2x 100k resistors
Here is the file just below

[image]

Comment: It’s commendable that you included wiring, but I think it would be easier to read if you included a schematic. Also I don’t quite understand what you are doing, notably with those two resistors, the lack of connection to GND, the weird connections to SCK, the purpose of the buttons, the weird colour choices (or weird wiring, not sure which)… also we don’t really know what you are trying to achieve so it’s a bit difficult to have any idea whether it makes sense or not.